# Python writing my class with "with statement"

Tags: python, with-statement

I want to initiate my class with "with as statament".I am using pyodbc module to connect mssql.

```
import pyodbc

class Db:
    DRIVER   =  r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
    SERVER   =  r'SERVER=192.168.1.1,1433;'
    DATABASE =  r'DATABASE=Client;'
    USERNAME =  r'UID=sa;' 
    PASSWORD =  r'PWD=1'    

    def __init__(self):
        self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.DRIVER + self.SERVER + self.DATABASE + self.USERNAME + self.PASSWORD)
        self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()                

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("__exit__")
        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnxn.close()   


with Db() as d:
    print(d)
```

Above code is working fine but when I changed the SERVER name, it crashed and I cant see print("**exit**") at the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__exit__` method is only called if the `with` block is entered. Not the `with` statement, but the block of code attached to it.

If `Db()` throws an exception then neither `__enter__` nor `__exit__` are called. If you think about it, how could they be? The `Db` object was never successfully constructed, so there's no way its methods could be called.

Comment: Is there a good way writing  "with statement " in this condition?

Comment: I would not open a long-lived cursor. Open them and close them as needed using `with cnxn.cursor() as cursor`. That gets rid of the need to even have a `Db` wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the code though, I would put `DB` connection in a try except block and call `__exit__` function within that.

Also, making use of use of `traceback` will help you print / retrieve `stacktrace`, if that's what you are looking for.

> traceback — Print or retrieve a stack traceback
>   This module provides a standard interface to extract, format and print stack traces of Python programs. It exactly mimics the behavior of the Python

See [these python docs on traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html).

In my case I am just running your code so it will throw odbc error. On you system you may get different error.

**Your modified Code**

```
import traceback
import sys

class Db:
    DRIVER   =  r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
    SERVER   =  r'SERVER=192.168.1.1,1433;'
    DATABASE =  r'DATABASE=Client;'
    USERNAME =  r'UID=sa;' 
    PASSWORD =  r'PWD=1'    

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.DRIVER + self.SERVER + \
                        self.DATABASE + self.USERNAME + self.PASSWORD)
        except Exception:
            self.__exit__(sys.exc_info())

        self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()                

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    #def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    def __exit__(self, exc_msg):
        print("__exit__")
        print(exc_msg)
        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnxn.close() 

with Db() as d:
    print(d)
```

**Result**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
__exit__
    (<type 'exceptions.NameError'>, NameError("global name 'pyodbc' is not  
  defined",), <traceback object at 0x029ACC60>)
```